# Trying to create a view from another view? Oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an assignment that I've been  trying to solve for a while but I couldn't

The first question of the is "1.    Create a view VE1 that will customer_id, cust_title and the total amount for each customer."
so I created the first view

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "VE_1" ("CUST_ID", "CUST_TITLE", "TOTAL_AMOUNT") AS 
  SELECT Customer.cust_id,customer.cust_title,
SUM(lead.amount) AS Total_amount
FROM customer,lead
WHERE customer.cust_id=lead.cust_id
GROUP BY customer.cust_id,customer.cust_title
ORDER BY customer.cust_id
/
```

So after I created view one (which I'm not sure if it's the right answer or not). this question two which is the main reason that I've posted this question
"You want the same group results as in 1 but only for customers with total amount more than 25,000 (HAVING). Can you do it with a consecutive view VE2 from VE1, if not why? If cannot do it as consecutive do it as new view VE3".
so I tried this code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "VE_2" ("CUST_ID", "CUST_TITLE", "TOTAL_AMOUNT") AS 
  SELECT VE_1.cust_id,VE_1.cust_title,
SUM(lead.amount) AS Total_amount
FROM VE_2
WHERE customer.cust_id=lead.cust_id
GROUP BY customer.cust_id,customer.cust_title
HAVING
    count( amount ) > 25000
ORDER BY customer.cust_id
/
```

and it said "Compilation failed,line 0 (17:14:40)
ORA-01731: circular view definition encountered"

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

You get the error, because you're trying to select from the view you're just about to create. Additionally you refer to `customer` and `lead` which aren't introduced in the `FROM` clause. So that must fail too.

You can almost reuse all of your statement for the first view to get the second. Just add a `HAVING` clause.

```
CREATE
 OR REPLACE VIEW ve_2
                 (cust_id,
                  cust_title,
                  total_amount)
AS
SELECT customer.cust_id,
       customer.cust_title,
       sum(lead.amount) AS total_amount
       FROM customer
            INNER JOIN lead
                       ON customer.cust_id = lead.cust_id
       GROUP BY customer.cust_id,
                customer.cust_title
       HAVING sum(lead.amount) > 25000;
```

You can also create the second view using the first one. But instead of a `HAVING` clause, here you'd need to use a `WHERE` clause as the data is already aggregated.

```
CREATE
 OR REPLACE VIEW ve_2
                 (cust_id,
                  cust_title,
                  total_amount)
AS
SELECT ve_1.cust_id,
       ve_1.cust_title,
       ve_1.total_amount
       FROM ve_1
       WHERE ve_1.total_amount > 25000;
```

Comment: But the question in the assignment explicitly asking me to create a view 2 from view 1 while using the “having clause” or is it impossible to do so?

Comment: @Tatal: Well, you. if `cust_id` is unique, which seems to make sense, you could select from the first view, group by all columns and use `HAVING`. But that would be more of an abuse of aggregation than anything else and I hope nobody is trying to teach you such nonsense. I'd also not necessarily read the exercise like you. For me is doesn't say you have to aggregate the first view again. But to be certain, you'd have to discuss that with the person who gave you the exercise.

Comment: I tried your way using "where" clause instead of "having" clause but it said ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended, dunno what's the reason

Comment: Works fine for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9a616052cd660cb498183edad088af16 You must have changed something.